# Is there maybe a <select></select> popup Jquery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image: example]

Hy,
my Picture describes very good what iam searching for..Its ap popup/modal box with 2 select option...only 1 can be choosen

What iam serching for is a popup Window with different select options....maybe in buttons....or as Pictures...i dont want to use the Standard select Element...
Is/are there any nice Example...Codepen....Jquery plugin/plugins that can be used to solve this easily?

Thank You very much

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this correctly, but you are looking for dropdown list that does not use `<select>`, is that right?

Comment: yes  i want to replace the <select> with somting else

Comment: Stick with the `<select>` and add some CSS to style it (yes, it is possible). Less code that way. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/UTLtq/ Otherwise, use jQuery, Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4Zw32/

Comment: sure its possible but my options have a very long text and there is the select element not the best option for me....the answer from Kevin P will help me to solve my problem.....Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with fancybox and jQuery.

https://jsfiddle.net/axanj0n5/4/

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.0.47/jquery.fancybox.min.css"/>


<div style="display: none; width:500px;" id="hidden-content">

    <h2>Lightbox</h2>

    <a href="#" id="button-one" class="btn btn-lg btn-default select-btn" data-value="1">Select me 1</a>
    <a href="#" id="button-one" class="btn btn-lg btn-default select-btn" data-value="2">Select me 2</a>
</div>

<div class="container">


    <a data-fancybox data-src="#hidden-content" href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">
        Open Lightbox
    </a>
    <p>
        Selected Value<br>
        <input type="text" name="selected_value" id="selected_value"/>
    </p>
</div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.0.47/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('body').on('click', '.select-btn', function () {
            $selectBtn = $('.select-btn');
            $selectBtn.addClass('btn-default');

            $selectBtn.removeClass('btn-success');

            $(this).removeClass('btn-default');
            $(this).addClass('btn-success');

            $('#selected_value').val($(this).data('value'));
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Happy to help. Will you mark this as the accepted answer and let me know if you need any further guidance.

Comment: Thanks again just a little ....maybe useful note....adding a jQuery.fancybox.close(); after $(this).addClass('btn-success'); will auto-close the fancybox after selection :)